# Binding a C# class to XAML for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, mvvm

Ok, so I've been grinding away for hours now and still can't figure out why my data in my ViewModel is not being bound to my XAML in my main page. I even started an new project and implemented it fine the same way so I'm thinking it might have to do with namespaces or something I'm less familiar with.

When my application launches I create a global ViewModel in App.cs which I use to bind data to my XAML view.

```
public HomeViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
    (App.Current as App).RootFrame.DataContext = (App.Current as App).ViewModel;
}
```

Then the HomeViewModel looks something like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    /***View Model***/

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {   
        PropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(delegate { });
    }

    public Profile CurrentProfile; /*EDIT: Missing {get;set;} Which is necessary for
                                    *any property, including ones below that I 
                                    *referenced in the XAML
                                    */

    public string NotificationImage; 

    public ButtonPanelPath UniversalButtonPath;

    public void setProfile(Profile p)
    {
        CurrentProfile = p;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentProfile");
    }
    .
    .
    ....rest of access methods and properties
```

Now when my program runs I am 100% sure that the data in HomeViewModel is getting updated and the NotifyPropertyChanged method is being called every time a new field is "set".

And this class is bound to the RootFrame right? So shouldn't I be able to access these fields in my main page's xaml? This is an example of part of the xaml in a stack panel in the main grid:

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Aqua" CornerRadius="20">
  <StackPanel Name="profileInfo"  DataContext="{Binding CurrentProfile}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="profileName" FontSize="26" 
               FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}" Name="userLevel" FontSize="32" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LevelName}" Name="levelName" FontSize="26" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PointsNeeded}" Name="pointsBar" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <Image x:Name="levelIcon" Source="{Binding PictureUrl}" 
             Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel> 
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

So here Level, LevelName, PointsNeeded and PictureUrl are all public fields in Profile (or CurrentProfile which is the specific instance of Profile I'm referencing). I tried Profile.[field] but that didn't work either. If anyone could tell me what I'm missing to complete the binding it would be greatly appreciated.

By the way the namespaces are as follows if that means anything
-MainPage is in MyApp.src.pages
-App is in MyApp
-HomeViewModel is in MyApp.src.classes

Thanks in advance for your helpful solutions/comments, if you'd like more data/info please just ask.

Comment: Ok so one big problem I found that helped out a lot was when you declare the properties do so like this:"public Profile CurrentProfile {get; set;}" instead of how it was done above. And do the same for all other properties you will refrence with INotifyPropertyChanged in the XAML

Comment: Glad you resolved your problem - if you figure out what was actually causing it please post as an answer!

Comment: There, I added the EDIT in the code portion, is that what you meant?

Comment: I actually meant that you should post an answer (below, in the answer section) however editing the question will also work. This way hopefully some future users will find this information helpful if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding you are looking for is {Binding Proptery.SubProperty}.

So in your case for example {Binding CurrentProfile.Level}.

You are having an instance of your "HomeViewModel" in the DataContext, so you can access all of its propteries. If there is a complex type as a property, you have to access the property, the instance of the complex type not the type, to access its "sub"-properties.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using {Binding Property.SubPropery} but it doesn't work. That's why I was trying to bind CurrentProfile to the StackPanel and then just access the sub-properties from within but obviously that's not working either. Any more ideas?

Comment: I feel like it's not even regonizing that it's bound to that class, is there a quick and easy way to test to make sure (besides what i'm doing already) maybe in the debugger or something?

Comment: Can you bind a direct property of HomeViewModel? "NotificationImage" for example. And you have to create properties, public fields do not work as I know...

Comment: Yup, I got it working now, I'll accept your answer since your the only one who responded. I think the main problem was not having the {get; set;} for my properties as well as a few binding issues in the way I used it. Other then that I think I did a pretty good job of MVVM implementation.

Comment: Don't agree with this answer. If the StackPanel binds to `CurrentProfile` then children of the StackPanel retain that data context.

Comment: Wow... you are right Kirk... have not seen this binding... So to sum it up: If you want to bind something, it has to be a proptery ({get; set;}). You can always access propteries of your current context by {Binding Proptery}. If the property is a complex type and you want to access a "subproperty" it has to be {Binding ComplexTypeProperty.SubProperty}.

Comment: Yah your both right, what Kirk was saying is what I was doing to start with. Once you bind the property to the to stack panel then your can just reference the sub-properties directly because it's data context is now the property you bound to the stack panel. The reason that THIS example was not working for me was because I wasn't using the {get; set;} in my property definitions.

Comment: Without {get; set;} a property is not a property but a "public field". This is a difference for reflection which is used for XAML bindings

Comment: I am well informed of this now, as I wasn't when I previously asked this question, thanks all for your help.